# Eliminating variables from matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Say you have two linear systems
$$Ax=y$$

$$Bu=v$$

It's possible to combine these into a single larger equation, as follows

$$\begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\0 & B\\\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\u\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}y\\v\end{bmatrix}$$

However, if you know that $x_i=u_j$ and $y_i=u_j$ for some $i$ and $j$ then it's possible to eliminate two columns of the matrix and two rows of the matrix by a few relatively simple steps (equating two of the linear equations and substituting for the old variables).

Firstly, what is this operation called? Presumably this is a well-studied and commonly used operation.

Secondly (although with an answer to the first I may be able to figure this out), how efficiently can it be done as a property of how large the original matrices are and how many pairs of variables can be eliminated. Particularly if the matrices are very sparse.

Here's a full worked example of the reduction I'm describing:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b&0&0\\c&d&0&0\\0&0&e&f\\0&0&g&h\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\u_3\\u_4\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\\v_4\end{bmatrix}$$

Given that $u_2=u_3$ and $v_2=v_3$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b&0\\c&d&0\\0&e&f\\0&g&h\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\u_4\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_2\\v_4\end{bmatrix}$$

Which gives $cu_1+du_2=eu_2+fu_4$, so $u_2=\frac{c}{e-d}u_1+\frac{-f}{e-d}u_4$. Substituting gives:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a+\frac{c}{e-d}b&
\frac{-f}{e-d}b\\
\frac{c}{e-d}g&
h+\frac{-f}{e-d}g\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_4\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_4\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Gaussian elimination? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Comment: Doesn't Gaussian elimination normally operate on an augmented matrix? Here we only are operating on the matrix, rather than on the whole system of equations (x/y/u/v are purely symbolic).

Comment: Ok. I see your point, so maybe you just want to write the matrix in a row echelon form? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you'd apply it. I've added an example of a calculation to the question, maybe you could show how it would be done with Gaussian elimination?

Comment: I see what you mean, I do not think that that has a name. I think that it is just to write the system of equations again reducing the matrix.